# Jetty embedded restart server HTTPS connector after certificate change

Tags: ssl, certificate, jetty, keystore

We use the ACME protocol to automatically and programmatically request and generate new server certificates for SSL in conjunction with an embedded Jetty 9 web server (the Jetty server is configured and started with our own code, not a file based configuration).

As such, every 85 days or so, we wish to programmatically either:

1. change the `KeyStore` in the SSL configuration for the HTTPS `ServerConnector` (in `SSLContextFactory` or alike) if it is possible during runtime (but the existing `SSLContext` must somehow be refreshed),
2. restart the connector if it is possible after reconfiguration,
3. remove and stop the existing connector, create the new connector, add it to the server and start it (the connector).

How should we go about doing it the best way?

Comment: What is the reason for this restart?

Comment: The reason is that the keystore changes in real time. A new server certificate chain is received from Let's Encrypt.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Did you figure this out? I am trying to restart a connector during runtime, and I could use a few pointers.